# Getting to Wikipedia's "Philosophy" article using Python

Tags: python, performance, web-scraping

On Wikipedia, if you click the first non-italicised internal link in the main text of an article that's not within parentheses, and then repeat the process, you usually end up on the "Philosophy" article (see  [this Wikipedia essay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Getting_to_Philosophy)).

To test this idea, I made a simple Python module that does the "clicking" programmatically. Here's the code:

```
"""
The Philosophy Game
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Clicking on the first non-parenthesized, non-italicized link,
in the main text of a Wikipedia article, and then repeating
the process for subsequent articles, usually eventually gets
one to the Philosophy article. (See
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Getting_to_Philosophy
for more information)

The Philosophy Game, written in Python, lets you do the clicking
programmatically.

Basic usage:

    >>> from philosophy import PhilosophyGame
    >>> game = PhilosophyGame('Python (programming language)')
    >>> for s in game.trace():
    ...     print(s)
    ...
    >>>

Handling errors:
    >>> from philosophy import *
    >>> game = PhilosophyGame('Python (programming language)')
    >>> try:
    ...     for s in game.trace():
    ...         print(s)
    ... except ConnectionError:
    ...     sys.exit('Network error, please check your connection')
    ... except MediaWikiError as e:
    ...     sys.exit('MediaWiki API error {1}: {2}'.format(e.errors['code'],
    ...                                                e.errors['info']))
    ... except LoopException:
    ...     sys.exit('Loop detected, exiting...')
    ... except InvalidPageNameError as e:
    ...     sys.exit(e)
    ... except LinkNotFoundError as e:
    ...     sys.exit(e)

Advanced options:

In this example, we set `end` to 'Multicellular organism', so that
instead of stopping at 'Philosophy', trace() stops there.
    >>> game = PhilosophyGame(page='Sandwich', end='Multicellular organism'):

In the following example, we set `dont_stop` to True, so that
trace() disregards the value of `end` and doesn't stop.
    >>> game = PhilosophyGame(page='Sliced bread', dont_stop=True)

Note that trace() will always raise exceptions in case a loop
is detected or if valid link cannot be found within the page.
"""

import requests
import urllib
from requests.exceptions import ConnectionError
import lxml.html as lh

class MediaWikiError(Exception):
    """
    Raised when the MediaWiki API returns an error.
    """
    def __init__(self, message, errors):
        super(MediaWikiError, self).__init__(message)
        self.errors = errors

class LoopException(Exception):
    """
    Raised when a loop is detected.
    """
    pass

class InvalidPageNameError(Exception):
    """
    Raised when an invalid page name is
    passed to self.trace().
    """
    pass

class LinkNotFoundError(Exception):
    """
    Raised when no valid link is found
    after parsing.
    """
    pass

class PhilosophyGame():
    """
    The main PhilosophyGame class.
    """
    BASE_URL = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php'
    HEADERS = { 'User-Agent': 'The Philosophy Game/0.1' }
    def __init__(self, page=None, end='Philosophy', dont_stop=False):
        """
        Initialize object with initial page name to start with.

        Args:
            page: the initial page name to start with. (optional,
            defaults to a random page)

        Raises:
            InvalidPageNameError: if page is not a valid mainspace
            page name
        """
        if page is None:
            params = dict(action='query', list='random', rnlimit=1,
                        rnnamespace=0, format='json')
            result = requests.get(self.BASE_URL, params=params,
                                headers=self.HEADERS).json()
            if 'error' in result:
                raise MediaWikiError('MediaWiki error',
                    result['error'])
            self.page = result['query']['random'][0]['title']
        else:
            self.page = page

        if not PhilosophyGame.valid_page_name(self.page):
            raise InvalidPageNameError("Invalid page name '{0}'"
                                        .format(self.page))
        self.link_count = 0
        self.visited = []
        self.end = end
        self.dont_stop = dont_stop

    @staticmethod
    def strip_parentheses(string):
        """
        Remove parentheses from a string, leaving
        parentheses between <tags> in place

        Args:
            string: the string to remove parentheses from
        Returns:
            the processed string after removal of parentheses
        """
        p = a = 0
        result = ''
        for c in string:
            # When outside of parentheses within <tags>
            if p < 1:
                if c == '<':
                    a += 1
                if c == '>':
                    a -= 1

            # When outside of <tags>
            if a < 1:
                if c == '(':
                    p += 1
                if p > 0:
                    result += ' '
                else:
                    result += c
                if c == ')':
                    p -= 1

            # When inside of <tags>
            else:
                result +=c

        return result

    @staticmethod
    def valid_page_name(page):
        """
        Checks for valid mainspace Wikipedia page name
        """
        return (page.find('File:') == -1
            and page.find('File talk') == -1
            and page.find('Wikipedia:') == -1
            and page.find('Wikipedia talk:') == -1
            and page.find('Project:') == -1
            and page.find('Project talk:') == -1
            and page.find('Portal:') == -1
            and page.find('Portal talk:') == -1
            and page.find('Special:') == -1
            and page.find('Help:') == -1
            and page.find('Help talk:') == -1
            and page.find('Template:') == -1
            and page.find('Template talk:') == -1
            and page.find('Talk:') == -1
            and page.find('Category:') == -1
            and page.find('Category talk:') == -1)

    def trace(self, page=None, whole_page=False):
        """
        Visit the first non-italicized, not-within-parentheses
            link of page recursively until the page self.end
            (default: 'Philosophy') is reached.

        Args:
            page: The Wikipedia page name to start with
            (optional, defaults to self.page)
        Returns:
            A generator with the page names generated in sequence
            in real time (including self.end).
        Raises:
            MediaWikiError: if MediaWiki API responds with an error
            requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: if cannot initiate request
            LoopException: if a loop is detected
            InvalidPageNameError: if invalid page name is passed as argument
            LinkNotFoundError: if a valid link cannot be found for
            page
        """

        if page is None:
            page = self.page

        if not PhilosophyGame.valid_page_name(page):
            raise InvalidPageNameError("Invalid page name '{0}'"
                    .format(page))
        params = dict(action='parse', page=page, prop='text',
                    format='json', redirects=1)

        if not whole_page:
            params['section'] = 0

        result = requests.get(self.BASE_URL, params=params,
                    headers=self.HEADERS).json()

        if 'error' in result:
            raise MediaWikiError('MediaWiki error',
                result['error'])

        title = result['parse']['title'].encode('utf-8')

        # Don't yield if whole page requested
        # (which should only be done as a second attempt)
        if not whole_page:
            yield title

        # This needs to be done AFTER yield title
        # (The only) normal termination
        if not self.dont_stop and page == self.end:
            return
        raw_html = result['parse']['text']['*'].encode('utf-8')
        html = lh.fromstring(raw_html)

        # This takes care of most MediaWiki templates,
        # images, red links, hatnotes, italicized text
        # and anything that's strictly not text-only
        for elm in html.cssselect('.reference,span,div,.thumb,'
                                + 'table,a.new,i,#coordinates'):
            elm.drop_tree()

        html = lh.fromstring(PhilosophyGame.strip_parentheses(
                            lh.tostring(html)))
        link_found = False
        for elm, attr, link, pos in html.iterlinks():
            # Because .iterlinks() picks up 'src' and the like too
            if attr != 'href':
                continue
            next_page = link

            # Must be a valid internal wikilink
            if next_page[:len('/wiki/')] != '/wiki/':
                continue

            # Extract the Wikipedia page name
            next_page = next_page[len('/wiki/'):]

            # Decode escaped characters
            next_page = urllib.unquote(next_page)

            # Skip non-valid names
            if not PhilosophyGame.valid_page_name(next_page):
                continue

            # Links use an underscore ('_')
            # instead of a space (' '), this
            # fixes that
            next_page = next_page.replace('_', ' ')

            # Eliminate named anchor, if any
            pos = next_page.find('#')
            if pos != -1:
                next_page = next_page[:pos]

            # Detect loop
            if next_page in self.visited:
                raise LoopException('Loop detected')

            link_found = True
            self.link_count += 1
            self.visited.append(page)

            for m in self.trace(next_page):
                yield m

            break
        if not link_found:
            if whole_page:
                raise LinkNotFoundError(
                        'No valid link found in page "{0}"'.format(
                            page.encode('utf-8')))
            else:
                for m in self.trace(page, whole_page=True):
                    yield m
```

Basic usage of the module would be something like:

```
from philosophy import PhilosophyGame

game = PhilosophyGame()
for page in game.trace():
    print(page)
```

The problem is, it takes a long time to fetch the result of a [MediaWiki API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Main_page) query, parse it as JSON, extract the parsed HTML text, remove text within parentheses and some tags (e.g. <i>), then get the first link, follow it and repeat the process.

To optimize the approach, I altered the `trace()` method so that instead of parsing the whole page, it only requests parsed text of the [lead section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MOS:LEAD) of a page, and only request the whole page as a second attempt when no link could be found the first time, but it's still pretty slow.

I do realize that using a local Wikipedia dump would speed up the whole process, but I was wondering if there was a way to optimize the existing approach.

Comment: In `trace()`, the expression `next_page[:len('/wiki/')] != '/wiki/'` is equivalent to `not next_page.startswith('/wiki/')`.

Comment: `it takes a long time to fetch the result of a MediaWiki API query, parse it as JSON, extract the parsed HTML text, remove text within parentheses and some tags (e.g. <i>), then get the first link` do you have some timing measurement to support this? Do you know which part is the slowest? Which part can you actually improve?

Comment: @oliverpool: I just did a timing test using line_profiler (which basically tells you about the time each line in your code took) and apparently in both `__init__()` and `trace()`, fetching the contents of the GET request is what took the most time (over 90% in both cases). I changed the headers to include `Accept-Encoding: gzip` (MediaWiki supports gzip) but the improvement wasn't much (39.5474 to 37.3156 seconds with "Koseč" as the starting point).

Comment: @Sumit : so even if you drastically improve the Python code, you can't get much more than a 10% improvement without a dump

Answer (score 5):

**Reduce repetition**

```
@staticmethod
def valid_page_name(page):
    """
    Checks for valid mainspace Wikipedia page name
    """
    return (page.find('File:') == -1
        and page.find('File talk') == -1
        and page.find('Wikipedia:') == -1
        and page.find('Wikipedia talk:') == -1
        and page.find('Project:') == -1
        and page.find('Project talk:') == -1
        and page.find('Portal:') == -1
        and page.find('Portal talk:') == -1
        and page.find('Special:') == -1
        and page.find('Help:') == -1
        and page.find('Help talk:') == -1
        and page.find('Template:') == -1
        and page.find('Template talk:') == -1
        and page.find('Talk:') == -1
        and page.find('Category:') == -1
        and page.find('Category talk:') == -1)
```

`and page.find` and `== -1` are repeated \$16\$ times. Use a generator comprehension instead:

```
return all(page.find(non_main) == -1 for non_main in NON_MAIN_CATEGORIES)
```

Where `NON_MAIN_CATEGORIES` may be saved as a constant either top-level or inside this class.

**`in`**

Your usage of `find` looks like a weird substitute for `in`, you probably mean:

```
non_main not in page
```

When you use `.find == -1`

So at last we get:

```
return all(non_main not in page for non_main in NON_MAIN_CATEGORIES)
```

Some REPL example usage of `in` to clear this up:

```
>>> "example".find("e")
0
>>> "example".find("x")
1
>>> "example".find("z")
-1
>>> "example".find("z") == -1
True
>>> not "z" in "example"
True
>>> ("example".find("z") == -1) == (not "z" in "example")
True
>>> "z" not in "example" # Just some syntactic sugar
True
```

**Philosophy and string stripping: Separation of concerns**

Why is `strip_parentheses(string)` a method of the philosophy game class? Maybe you need this functionality inside the game, but it is a minor detail.

Think re-use, would anyone think that stripping parenthesis is put inside a class for Philosophy Wikipedia surfing?

Just put it free-floating or inside a `string_utils` module that you may import.

**Actually, why a class?**

Ignoring `__init__`, that any class must have, `valid_page_name` that is trivial, and `strip_parentheses` that should really not be there, the`PhilosophyGame` class just contains one function.

When you have only one function in a class, you can simplify and avoid the class completely.

```
def philosophy_game(start=None, end='Philosophy', ...):
    # Implementation
```

The usage also a little becomes easier:

```
print(list(philosophy_game('Dog')))
```

**Double negatives**

I find double negatives needlessly confusing.

```
if not self.dont_stop and page == self.end:
    return
```

Requires some thinking, while:

```
if self.should_end and page == self.end
```

Reads in a fraction of a second.

Or you may just use a noun instead of `dont` in the variable name:

```
if not self.infinite and page == self.end:
    return
```

Either is easier to understand than double negation.

Answer (score 1):

I don't like small trailing `else` blocks, I usually prefer to flip the conditions so it's easier to see what happens in each case:

```
    if page is not None:
        self.page = page
    else:
        params = dict(action='query', list='random', rnlimit=1,
                      rnnamespace=0, format='json')
        result = requests.get(self.BASE_URL, params=params,
                              headers=self.HEADERS).json()
        if 'error' in result:
            raise MediaWikiError('MediaWiki error',
                result['error'])
        self.page = result['query']['random'][0]['title']
```

It's also strange to instantiate a `dict` with the function instead of literal syntax. Why not just do this:

```
        params = {'action': 'query', 'list': 'random', 'rnlimit': 1,
                  'rnnamespace': 0, 'format': 'json'}
```

`strip_parentheses` is very confusing with all the single character names. What are `p` `c` and `a`? You seem to be using `a` for level of nesting, so why not `nesting_level`? `c` is `character` since it's the iteration of the string and `p` is, `nested_parentheses`? Even if you can't get an entirely clear name, you can do better than `p` and at least add a comment.